# collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath not fired if addGestureRecognizer to ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a `TextField`+`CollectionView` inside `ScrollView`
When user edit the text, the keyboard will appear then I want to hide the keyboard when user press on ScrollView so I use the code below in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)]];
```

But after I use this code, the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` not fired when I click on each item

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

How can I make the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` fired.
Any help would be great appreciated

Comment: Try adding a delegate to your gesture recognizer and implement the delegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`. The method should return YES

Comment: Gesture recogniser suddenly stopped working on iOS 9 or later. Just conform the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  all optional method and return YES will work.